# migrating database data from mssql to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-migration

mssql database has the data and I want to move it to mysql database. the tables that the data are coming from are not the same as the tables that i will be putting the data into. what i am thinking of is doing a select then putting the data in a json then inserting it to mysql. this way i know which data is going to which table and to which column. but i am thinking this would be very hard because the data is very big. there is a back up data and it is more than 1gb. so i dont think my solution would be appropriate.

***I am wondering is there a better solution for this problem?***

Comment: *the tables that the data are coming from are not the same as the tables that i will be putting the data into* there is no other way but to preprocess your data first before inserting them to mysql..

Comment: @BagusTesa what you are saying is the only way is like how i am thinking to do it? select then insert?

Answer (score 0):

One way, that seemed to work at another company I've worked at, was to normalize the data. Then write a dynamic db converter that worked with both postgres and mysql. This was written in Java.

With that being said, you need to make sure that the relational db model is the best option for your [data needs](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/relational-non-relational-databases). A No-SQL solution is better for data that is changing and not consistent.